# Export Firefox bookmarks WITH TAGS?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, export, browser-tabs

How can I create an export of my Firefox 6.01 bookmarks that includes tags?

I have tried main menu Bookmarks / Show All Bookmarks / Import and Export and then both "Backup" (which creates JSON) and "Export HTML" (which creates HTML) but neither of these includes tags. They include tons of other crap I couldn't care less about (like the favicon) but no tags. Seriously? What am I missing here? I've searched both Superuser and the web at large and can't find anything.

Comment: If you are willing to go third party, I think Xmarks will do what you want

Comment: As it turns out, I was mistaken, and the JSON does include tags. I'm not quite sure how I missed them, they are clearly there. Not sure if I should delete this question now?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem: I exported the bookmarks of my Firefox 10 as a JSON file. But I don't see there any tags. The only attributes I get are these:

```
charset
dateAdded
expires
flags
id
index
lastModified
livemark
mimeType
name
parent
root
title
type
uri
value
```

Or is it stored as a special child object?

Comment: After some research I saw that children are also stored as attributes: `annos` and `children`. But I still don't find any tags. :-(

Comment: Okay, I guess I've found it: All important objects have a "root" attribute. These objects are (first the title in the German version of Firefox, second the root attribute value): `` -> `placesRoot`, `Lesezeichen-Menü` -> `bookmarksMenuFolder`, `Lesezeichen-Symbolleiste` -> `toolbarFolder`, `Schlagwörter` -> `tagsFolder`, `Unsortierte Lesezeichen` -> `unfiledBookmarksFolder`.
And the object with the root attribute `tagsFolder` contains the tags as `children`. Every tag contains the tagged bookmarks as `children`.

Comment: That means you have some kind of "double structure": First the normal hierarchy structure of the bookmarks. Then you have a second structure of the tags containing "links" to the tagged bookmarks.

Comment: You can [edit] your post, you don't need to put everything into comments.

Comment: Have you found any "official" documentation of the bookmarks backup JSON file format? Your comments helped me decipher it, but having some developer documentation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported in Firefox, see [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=423197). Mike Frysinger created a patch to introduce this "feature" (see comment 15 in the bug report), but it seems to be not included in the main Firefox code until now. So, you can vote for this in the bug report to (hopefully) speed up the integration.

By the way, it is discussed to [remove the bookmark tagging](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622047)  from Firefox.

Comment: Supported in Firefox 43 that imports tags from html bookmarks. My sources and test: https://www.diigo.com/outliner/85adjv/Bookmarks-made-usable!-Sync%2C-merge-and-more# - Finally do your export, merge :)